# How do I install just the ksqlDB CLI tool on Linux?

Tags: command-line-interface, ksqldb

This seems like something that should be so simple!
(Every other CLI tool I use has an easy install process.)

We're running ksqlDB in a Kubernetes cluster, and I would like to connect to it with the CLI from my local machine (either Windows 10 or from WSL 2)

- The https://ksqldb.io/quickstart.html suggests using the CLI docker image, but I'm not thrilled with trying to connect to our Kubernetes cluster from a local docker image - seems like lots of opportunity for networking issues.
- https://www.confluent.io/download/ requires that I download all of Confluent community edition??   (1.2GB!  On my country internet)
- https://docs.confluent.io/4.1.2/ksql/docs/installation/installing.html#starting-the-ksql-cli seems to again expect that you've installed the entire server locally.   I don't need or want to run the server locally.
- The Github page doesn't provide any releases (thought maybe I could grab just the CLI here, but no luck).

Is this simply not possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest by far is indeed to use the Docker image. From the container, you can connect to your ksqlDB server the same as you would from your host machine.

```
docker run --interactive --tty --rm confluentinc/ksqldb-cli:0.12.0 \
       ksql https://my-ksqldb-server.foo.corp
```

Or if you have auth setup (e.g. if you were using Confluent Cloud):

```
docker run --interactive --tty --rm confluentinc/ksqldb-cli:0.12.0 \
       ksql --user myKsqlDBUser$KSQLDB_API_KEY \
            --password Admin123 \
            https://my-ksqldb-server.foo.corp
```

Comment: Thanks @robin-moffatt.
Unfortunately I am indeed now solving networking issues.
The Kafka cluster isn't directly accessible, so in my WSL 2 command line I'm port-forwarding the Kubernetes ksqlDB server port 8088, and trying to connect to that from within Docker (which isn't working yet).

This is why I wanted to simply install the ksqlDB CLI tool in my Linux environment and connect directly.

Comment: OK understand. Yeah that does sound fiddly. Have you tried `host.docker.internal` to access your local machine from the docker container?

Comment: Thanks for checking back!  :-)    I did, but there was some error connecting to the Kubernetes port-forward.

Answer (score 0):

Alright - he's how I was successfully able to connect.
I never did - unfortunately - find a way to easily install just the `ksql` CLI tool locally.

Nor did not end up using the local ksql-cli docker image with a Kubernetes port-forward to the cluster due to Docker networking issues.

Instead, I shelled directly into the Kubernetes ksqlDB server.
This tripped me up a bit because we're using the `cp-kafka` helm chart, and the ksqlDB pod runs two containers - so you have to ensure you're shelling into the correct container (and without specifying the container, you won't).

Here's the command I used:

```
kubectl -n kafka --stdin --tty name-of-ksql-server-pod -c cp-ksql-server --/bin/bash
```

`-n kafka` - using the kafka Kubernetes namespace

`--stdin --tty` - ensures I can shell in correctly

`-c cp-ksql-server` - the ksql server container within the pod.  I got this name by doing a `kubectl -n kafka describe pod name-of-ksql-server-pod` and then looking through the resulting list of containers.

Then a simple `ksql` at the command line was enough to successfully connect (without any localhost or anything).

Comment: It's 'kubectl exec ...'.

Answer (score 0):

Credit: https://luppeng.wordpress.com/2022/11/20/access-ksqldb-cli-inside-a-browser-using-ttyd/

This worked for me to connect to a ksqldb server running inside the docker instance as per the quick start:

For version 0.28.2 (change as needed):

1. Installation:

   ```
   curl http://ksqldb-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/archive/0.28/confluent-ksqldb-0.28.2.tar.gz --output confluent-ksqldb-0.28.2.tar.gz
   tar -xzf confluent-ksqldb-0.28.2.tar.gz
   ```
2. Run (change address as needed):

   ```
   confluent-ksqldb-0.28.2/bin/ksql http://myksqldbhost:8088
   ```